# How to calculate days between dates and get the average

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need help creating a formula. I'm really struggling with this.

On one sheet, i have a table that kind of looks like below:

```
            Received     Completed
Request 1   14/01/2020  21/01/2020
Request 2   15/01/2020  17/01/2020
Request 3   16/01/2020  16/01/2020
Request 4   14/01/2020  17/01/2020
```

On another sheet, I need to calculate the average number of days it takes to complete a request, not including the weekends. The number of requests varies, so I need this formula to automatically update as I add more rows on the first sheet. But this formula shouldn't include requests that are not completed yet (no second date provided)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(C2:C5<>"",NETWORKDAYS(N(IF({1},B2:B5)),N(IF({1},C2:C5)))))
```

Depending on one's version the formula may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

`N(IF({1},` creates an array of the dates.  `NETWORKDAYS(` returns the number of workdays between the dates.  `IF(C2:C5<>""` ignores those that do not have a date in Completed.  `AVERAGE`...well it AVERAGES.

[image]

---

Using the Dynamic Array Formula FILTER:

```
=AVERAGE(NETWORKDAYS(FILTER(B2:B5,C2:C5<>""),FILTER(C2:C5,C2:C5<>"")))
```

Note: FILTER is part of the Dynamic Array Formula and is available with Office 365 subscription.

Answer (score 0):

*This help you to achieve the goal.*

[image]

**How it works:**

**N.B.**

*- Since request are variable and you need the formula to auto update, therefore better covert the data range into TABLE.*

- Column F has list of Holidays (*you may add more dates*).

**Remember using HOLIDAYS is an optional.**

**Method 1:**

- Add new column **Net Days** in Table.
- Insert this formula in `D15`.

`=NETWORKDAYS([@Received],[@Completed],F$14)`

*- **If** you don't want to use HOLIDAYS then, use this one.*

`=NETWORKDAYS([@Received],[@Completed])`

- Formula in Cell `D21`:

`=AVERAGE(Table1[Net Days])`

**Method 2 (Without HOLIDAYS):**

- Formula in `D23`.

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Completed]-Table1[Received])/COUNT(Table1[Completed])
  ```

*You may adjust cell references.*